# addClass() jquery problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, addclass

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    var asd = '<div class="class-to-div1">' + '<div class="class-to-div  col-md-2 list">' + '<div class="add-list-item static">' + '<button id="add-div">press here to add div</button>' + '</div>' + '<div class="list-item placeholder">asdsdaljnfdasdasdf</div>' + '<div class="list-item placeholder">asdsdaljnfdasdasdf</div>' + '<div class="list-item placeholder">asdsdaljnfdasdasdf</div>' + ' <div class="list-item placeholder">asdsdaljnfdasdasdf</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
    //console.log(asd);
    $('.add-list').click(function () {
        $('.container').append(asd);
        $('class-to-div1').each(function (counter) {
            $(this).addClass('sortable-div-' + counter);
        });
        $('class-to-div').each(function (counter) {
            $(this).addClass('sortable-list-' + counter);
        });
        $('.sortable-div-' + counter).sortable({
            connectWith: '.sortable-div-' + counter,
        });
        $('.sortable-list-' + counter).sortable({
            connectWith: '.sortable-list' + counter - 1,
            fixed: '.static',
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
        $("#add-div" + counter).click(function () {
            var text = prompt("what should be inserted?");
            if (text === null) {
                alert("write something in new div");
            } else {
                $(".sortable-list-" + counter).append('<div class="list-item  placeholder">' + text + '</div>');
            }
        });
        counter++;
    });
});
```

So this is my code in which i create new divs by pressing button. i wanted to  drag them around like its on www.trello.com, but they are not moving. i think that addClass() is not the function i want so what should i do? button works fine, but the least code doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, prefix with `.`, if you are using [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
 $('.class-to-div1')
```

instead of

```
 $('class-to-div1')
```

You have same issue with `$('class-to-div')`

*i think that addClass() is not the function*, Definitely [**addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a function

### EDIT

Also you need to modify you [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), callback function provide you index as you where passing `counter` basically it was index

Change it to, remove counter parameter from .each()

```
    $('.class-to-div1').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('sortable-div-' + counter);
    });
```